# Can magnets break LED notification light on phone?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm posting this question here because it's about magnets and electronics. Please tell me if it's better suited to another site!

I've been messing around with some reasonably strong magnets around my Nexus 4 phone (yes, I know that's stupid). Now my LED notification light isn't working. Could the cause of this possibly be interference from the magnets?

The magnets are strongly attracted to each other - but not to my phone - and are like large capsules, about 5cm long and 1cm wide. I don't know exactly which metal they're made of but I'll hazard a guess at iron.

If you want any more details please ask me!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about design but about a failure of a commercial device.

Comment: ___________NO__

Comment: If it is off-topic then which site is best?

Comment: what did you do exactly with the magnets and your phone?

Comment: It is probable that something else caused the problem. There is no obvious way for the magnets to have caused the priobvlem - but Murphy does not always stick to obvious ways.

Answer (score 1):

Taking it as a design question, yes, it is possible.

In a typical design, the LED is driven by an output port on a CPU, microcontroller, or via a FET or transistor.  A loop of conductor runs to the LED and returns.  The return path may not follow the outbound path.  A rapidly changing and strong magnetic field can induce current into the PFC or PCB trace that connects to the LED.  This current may do damage to the driving circuit or the LED.

However, it would have to be a quite significant magnetic field to generate enough current for enough time to do damage.

I'm talking like the sort of fields found in an nMRI machine.  I've never heard of handheld magnets doing this.  It seems more likely that the failure was caused by ESD or physical force.

Comment: As James said, sudden change in magnetic field could have damaged it as it induces emf on the traces that have big enough loop inductances. But usually, phone pcb would have ground layers very close to the signal carrying traces which has negligible loop inductance. Those devices should be tested under EMC/EMI tests. However, this damage is still possible if your magnet is really really strong!